# How suitable is the term "blacks" to specify an ethnic group?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

I recently came across a medical article that accounted for a number of <strike>ethnic</strike> physiological profiles (women, blacks and diabetics) when interpreting the outcome of a trial. They consistently used the term "blacks", presumably for subjects of African descent.

My question is, how specific is the term "blacks" as an ethnic profile; what does and what doesn't it entail? And on a related note, how laden is the term "blacks"? In my native tongue "blacks" and "niggers" carry about the same connotation.

---

### Edit in response to the comments

Thank you all for your comments. From your responses I distill that "blacks" is more or less equivalent to "African-American", but might carry a negative connotation.

@Xanne: *"physiological profile" might have been more accurate than "ethnic profile", although I reckon the line between these two is blurred in the current context.*

@Mitch *There is a perceived difference between 'black' (the adjective for the group) and 'blacks' (the group label). Even though this seems infinitesimally different, they have pretty different connotations.*

@AndyT *"Black" is not equivalent to "African American". All African Americans may be Blacks, but not all Blacks are African Americans. There are plenty of black people who are not American!*

Most responses have been concerning the connotation of the term "blacks". I would like to shift the focus to my other question:
Does anyone think that "blacks" may refer to a more specific or a more broad group than "African-American"?

Comment: What's your mother tongue? You don't know that  the term *nigger* is a highly offensive term in all Anglophone countries? You don't know that there is any difference between saying Blacks and the N-word?  There's a reason why it's also called that.

Comment: Suitable to whom, in what context, for what purpose? Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: [Afro-American](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Afro-American)/African-American is the acceptable term

Comment: In the US, "nigger" is highly offensive.  "Black" is less so, but is losing ground to "African-American" and "people of color" (which refers to any ethnic group with dark skin).  "Colored" used to be the "polite" term for "nigger", but passed out of favor maybe 30 years ago.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In daily life, at least here in the States, no one actually says "Afro-American", though "African-American" is very common. I'd say that it's safest to stick with that if you are not a member of that community.

Comment: If you're worried, ask the people you're worried about offending what **they** think. Nobody else's opinion counts, after all.

Comment: The hazards of ethnic identities are nowhere better illustrated that in apartheid South Africa where, to support business interests, the National Party government granted "honorary white" status to Japanese, Korean and Taiwanese citizens.

Comment: In U.S. cities, one often hears the distinction made between African-American and Afro-Caribbean.  What term best encompasses both and other geographical areas?  Medical  articles probably need to use a generalized term unless the study is focused on a particular geographical area and is not generalizable.

Comment: You talk about ethnic profiles in a medical article, in which you include (or claim the article includes) women, blacks, and diabetics.  That seems to me to be peculiar for a research study.  You should provide a link to the study or a long enough quotation to provide context.

Comment: @Xanne, why do you think such categories would be unusual for a medical article?  Many medical conditions affect different groups very differently -- gender, ethnic background, age, etc.  Certain subgroups have much higher prevalence of certain diseases.  Different groups respond to certain treatments differently.  Differentiating gender and ethnicity (and other relevant groupings), in association with a particular disease is a basic, necessary practice in any medical research in order to get meaningful results.  Otherwise big factors become noise, hiding what you need to measure.

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree with you summary here, of course, but the OP talks about "ethnic profiles (women, blacks and diabetics)".  Perhaps I should simply forgive this sloppiness.

Comment: The US has developed a grievance industry. People have discovered political and social power in being offended. There are "language police" on college campuses who manage to find so many words offensive that it becomes difficult to communicate.  Almost any word can be claimed to offend somebody, or have potential to offend somebody.  You can take reasonable steps to be sensitive to what are considered mainstream offensive words.  But the rampant abuse of being offended and seeing micro-aggressions in everything is a form of bullying, and well-intentioned people facilitate it by buying into it.

Comment: There is a perceived difference between 'black' (the adjective for the group) and 'blacks' (the group label). Even though this seems infinitesimally different, they have pretty different connotations. Let me give an analogous situation. "The English eat disgusting food." vs "English people eat disgusting food". The first one sounds like it is an inherent almost defining property of being English. The second one sounds like it is a consequence of external factors (where they live, circumstances of food production). Translate to any ethnicity.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The same interpretation is not true for all cultures. In Dutch, for example, "neger" is still accepted usage (since it is still considered as the Latin word for black). However, calling someone a "zwarte" (black, as a noun) is interpreted as being dismissive of the person other than their race. "Zwarte vriend" (black friend), however, is not considered dismissive but merely descriptive. I know we're on English.SE and not Dutch.SE, but though this cultural difference is relevant to the question at hand, even if only tangential.

Comment: @Mitch: is that difference not caused by the omission of a definite article? "Black people are drinking beer" is a blanket statement, whereas "the black people are drinking beer" could be talking about e.g. the black people in a certain room (not a blanket statement).

Comment: @Flater I did say Anglophone countries, that excludes any nation whose mother tongue is not English. But it's worthwhile pointing that out. If I were you, outside the Netherlands,  I would not call any black person a "neger". It will be taken as an offence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Not a Dutchie, so technically already going against your advice :p My comment wasn't meant to correct yours, but rather append to it. I am aware of the implications of using it outside a Dutch speaking zone.

Comment: "Black" is not equivalent to "African American". All African Americans may be Blacks, but not all Blacks are African Americans. There are plenty of black people who are not American!

Comment: @Flater re "difference caused by omission of article" 1) 'cause' is not really how it works. Natural language is not 'compositional' (things are not the sum of its distinct parts, things interact in many ways). 2) It is both the plural and the definite article together that trigger a different meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are official US racial definitions that government agencies follow, in a accordance with a Office of Management and Budget (OMB) directive, as [explained here](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/guide/notice-files/NOT-OD-15-089.html).  Two of the definitions are

> **Black or African American**. A person having origins in any of the black racial groups of Africa. Terms such as "Haitian" or "Negro" can be used in addition to "Black or African American."
>
> **White**. A person having origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the Middle East, or North Africa

So keep in mind that some original people of Africa and their descendants, for example of Egypt, Libya, Tunisia, Algeria, etc., are considered "white", at least according to official US definitions.

The term "African-American" came into wide-spread usage after Jesse Jackson endorsed in 1988, as explained in the 31 January 1989 New York Times article ['African-American' Favored By Many of America's Blacks](http://www.nytimes.com/1989/01/31/us/african-american-favored-by-many-of-america-s-blacks.html?pagewanted=all).

However, subsequently there has been some backlash against this term from blacks.  See for example:

[Why I'm Black, not African American](http://articles.latimes.com/2004/sep/08/news/0e-mcwhorter8) *Los Angles Times* 08 September 2004.

[I'm Not African American, I'm Black](http://www.ebony.com/news-views/im-not-african-american-im-black#axzz4hclYTwUJ) *Ebony* 2012

Even Jesse Jackson was recently (4 April 2017) quoted as saying the phrase "blacks building slave ships", as explained in [Rev. Jesse Jackson: Latinos Building Border Wall is Like Blacks Building Slave Ships](http://www.nbcnews.com/news/latino/rev-jesse-jackson-latinos-building-border-wall-blacks-building-slave-n742941)

The naming of black organizations such as [Blacks in Government](http://www.bignet.org/) and [National Association of Blacks In Criminal Justice](http://nabcj.org/) further shows that "blacks" is not an offensive term.

Comment: "Black" (adj) has different connotation than "Blacks" (plural noun), so this answer is off the mark.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger "Blacks" is in the title of the New York Times article of the answer.  "Blacks" is used 12 times in the body of the NYT article.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger I added a recent Jesse Jackson quote using the word "blacks", to supplement the answer.

Comment: So we know that 1. NYT used this term in the 1980's. 2. Jesse Jackson uses the term. That's still not quite convincing that "blacks" is a preferred term in USA circa 2017.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger I'm just saying it's not offensive (especially in contrast to the OP using the N-word), not that "blacks" is always the most preferred term for every situation.  The House of Representatives uses "Black Americans" http://history.house.gov/Exhibitions-and-Publications/BAIC/Historical-Data/Black-American-Representatives-and-Senators-by-Congress/ .  "Black folks" is often good.

Comment: I agree with @ColinZwanziger—where possible, it is preferable to use Black as an adjective (e.g. *Black participants*) rather than as a noun. That doesn't mean the noun is entirely offensive, but it does sound out-of-date.

Comment: @1006a Last week the New York Times has a headline "Poll Says Blacks Less Likely to Have Enough for Retirement".  https://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2017/05/18/us/ap-us-ap-poll-retirement-race.html?_r=0 and in the body "blacks earn less than whites".

Comment: Yes, it still appears, especially in situations like headlines or statistics where brevity is especially important. That doesn't mean it's best practice for everyday situations.

Answer (score 0):

1. How specific is the term "blacks" as an ethnic profile?  What does and doesn't it entail?

a. For medical research about people living in the U.S. (as in the case of the article you read), "black" as a racial category is clearly enough understood that, as you saw, the author didn't feel a need to define the term.  (You might be able to get more information about this at Health.SE.)

b. In the U.S., outside the world of medicine, how an individual self-identifies has become more important than arbitrarily assigned designations.

2. How laden is the term "blacks"?

In the U.S. there is a tremendous legacy of racism and unresolved misunderstandings, fair and unfair assumptions, hypersensitivities and resentments.  As shown in some of the comments on this page, even the existence of feelings of resentment sometimes provokes irate reactions.  In other words, when you asked this question, you stepped unknowingly into a minefield.

There are many possible permutations of speaker and listener, writer and reader.  Ordered pairs can be made by selecting from the following: white person, black person, African American person (with subsets by age, urban vs. rural, etc.), international black person (with *many* subsets, such as visitor, recent immigrant, established immigrant, region of origin, etc.), mixed race person, and so on.

One could write a book about your question, considering all the possible permutations!

But you want some practical information.  Was the medical researcher's use of the word *black* offensive?  One would have to read the article to figure that out.  **As a non-native visiting or living in the U.S., can you safely use the word *black* as a synonym for *African American*?  Frequently, but not always.**

Example: Someone in my family recently needed a particular hair care product in a hurry before traveling. I called a certain department store and asked if they carried black hair care products.  The clerk took offense and told me to say "African American," not "black."

Moral of the story: one should be prepared to be sensitive to individual preferences.

Comment: I think for hair, "black" is confusing because it could just refer to the color of the hair.  I would recommend "Do you carry **ethnic** hair products"? http://www.kmart.com/beauty-hair-care-ethnic-hair-care/b-25141

Comment: African Americans like Elon Musk might be ill advised to use "African American hair products"...